# An issue generating variables from a contaminated bivariate normal distribution

Tags: r, statistics

I have written this simple function in order to generate tuples from a contaminated bivariate normal distribution. What it does is perform a Bernoulli experiment and based on the outcome, which is either 1 or 0, sample from one of two distributions.

```
require(mvtnorm)
    rcn <- function(n, covar1, sigma1, sigma2, eps, bias1, bias2, covar2){
          sigma1 <- matrix( c(sigma1, covar1, covar1, sigma2), ncol = 2, nrow = 2, byrow = T) ; 
          sigma2 <- matrix( c(sigma1, covar2, covar2, sigma2), ncol = 2, nrow = 2, byrow = T)
          m <- matrix(0, nrow = n, ncol = 2)
          for(i in 1:n){
            ind <- rbinom(1, 1, eps)
            m[i,] <- (1 - ind)*rmvnorm(1, sigma = sigma1) + ind*rmvnorm(1, sigma = sigma2, mean = c(bias1, bias2) )
          }
          list(y1 = m[,1], y2 = m[,2] )
        }


        rcn(20, 0.9, 1, 1, 0.05, 0, 0, -0.9)
```

The problem is that when I do that I get a warning I do not quite understand, namely

```
Warning message:
In matrix(c(sigma1, covar2, covar2, sigma2), ncol = 2, nrow = 2,  :
  data length [7] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of rows [2]
```

Could you please tell me what this is about? I have tried changing my code in many ways but unfortunately I cannot make it go away. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have overwritten `sigma1` with a matrix in your first line of the function but you use it in creating `sigma2` in the second line. The two lines of code you should change are these:

```
sigma1 <- matrix( c(sigma1, covar1, covar1, sigma2), ncol = 2, nrow = 2, byrow = T) ; 
sigma2 <- matrix( c(sigma1, covar2, covar2, sigma2), ncol = 2, nrow = 2, byrow = T)
```

Answer (score 1):

As answered you have overwritten your sigmas.  I reorganized your code to make it a bit more readable

```
require(mvtnorm)
rcn <- function(n, covar1, covar2, sigma1, sigma2, eps, bias1, bias2){

  Matrix1 <- 
    matrix( 
      c(sigma1, covar1
        , covar1, sigma2)
      , ncol = 2, nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)

  Matrix2 <- 
    matrix( 
      c(sigma1, covar2
        , covar2, sigma2)
      , ncol = 2, nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)

  m <- matrix(0, nrow = n, ncol = 2)

  for(i in 1:n){
    ind <- rbinom(1, 1, eps)
    m[i,] <- (1 - ind)*rmvnorm(1, sigma = Matrix1) + ind*rmvnorm(1, sigma = Matrix2, mean = c(bias1, bias2) )
  }

  list(y1 = m[,1], y2 = m[,2])

  }


rcn(20, 0.9, -0.9, 1, 1, 0.05, 0, 0)
```